# How to filter out specific rows in a dask dataframe using a custom function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have dataframe consisting of the following columns:

```
    act     section     female_judge    time_taken
0   17.0    121384.0    0 nonfemale        321.0
1   423.0   273193.0    0 nonfemale        0.0
2   423.0   332490.0    0 nonfemale        0.0
3   481.0   1440.0      0 nonfemale        0.0
4   481.0   5145.0      0 nonfemale        0.0
```

Basically I have grouped the records by the act,section and female_judge columns. **Now I want to keep the rows where for a given act and section, there exists both a row where the judge is female and a row where the judge is male.(I want to compare time taken between make and female judges for the same act and section).**

How would I filter out the rows?

Comment: Your labels are pretty confusing. `female_judge = 0 nonfemale` means the judges are all female?

Comment: No it means that the particular row is referring to a female judge. What I have shown in the question is just the head of the dataframe, the first 5 rows all show judges that are female, sorry about the confusion

Comment: I think you can solve this using groupby agg to get the length of each act-section combination. Filter that DataFrame for records where the length == 2. Inner join the filtered DataFrame back to the original DataFrame.